# Can I use bootstrap to deal with extremely small sample size?

Tags: t-test, svm, small-sample

I have two groups, each with 3 sets of data. For each dataset I train an SVM classifier to get a decoding accuracy, which I want to compare across groups. However, I only have 3 samples for each group - can I still run a t-test, or is it valid to bootstrap a distribution of decoding accuracies for each data set individually, and then compare the 6 total distributions?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "valid"?  Please bear in mind that the whole idea behind bootstrapping is to replace the process that generated your data by resampling from your data.  Do you feel confident that your data are sufficiently numerous to justify that substitution?  (It's hard to tell, because you don't distinguish "sets," "groups", "samples", and "distributions" with sufficient clarity to indicate how much data you really have.)

Comment: each dataset is of a decent size - >1000 values. the datasets are each taken from different individuals under the same conditions, whereas the groups are differentiated by different conditions. it seems to me that my data is getting reduced by application of the classifier, and that I could overcome this reduction by bootstrapping the classification step.

Answer (score -3):

You can use the bootstrap in such cases but the accuracy of any estimator of variance is problematic when the sample size is small. When the variance exists, the difference between the unbiased estimator and the biased estimator is just a factor of $(n-1)/n$.

Comment: Could you quantify what you mean by "small" and elaborate on how this interacts with the SVM classifier?  Why is a consideration of bias in estimating a variance relevant to assessing decoding accuracies?

Comment: Three would be a small sample size.

Comment: Did you note the comment thread?  The sample size does not appear to be three.